# No such file or directory using container in docker unrar

Tags: linux, docker, nas

I am trying to run the following docker container on my Terramaster NAS server. The container is
https://hub.docker.com/r/giejay/unrarall-arm64v8, which basically uses unrar 5.50 of linux.

I am new with the whole docker theme, and I want to use this, because I don't want to unzip files through FTP because it consumes many network resources, and I want to do it directly on the NAS.

For this I am using the following command

```
root@TNAS-010861: /mnt/Library#docker run giejay/unrarall-arm64v8 unrar e ~/mnt/Library/Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part1.rar
```

if I do an `ls -l` this is what appears to me in that directory

```
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 10737418240 Dec 27 13:25 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part1.rar
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 10737418363 Dec 27 13:25 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part1.rev
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 10737418240 Dec 27 13:25 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part2.rar
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 10737418240 Dec 27 13:25 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part3.rar
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 10737418240 Dec 27 13:25 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part4.rar
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 10737418240 Dec 27 13:26 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part5.rar
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 10737418240 Dec 27 13:25 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part6.rar
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 10737418240 Dec 27 13:25 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part7.rar
-rwxrwxrw- + 1 pedro allusers 3271810805 Dec 27 13:24 Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part8.rar
```

but every time I execute the command, I get the following error:

```
Cannot open /root/mnt/Library_/Library_2019.11.01_75.452.part1.rar
No such file or directory
No files to extract
[cmd] unrar exited 10
[cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts ...
[cont-finish.d] done.
[s6-finish] syncing disks.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the TERM signal.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the KILL signal and exiting.
```

What am I doing wrong?